# How to change boot order without using BIOS

Tags: boot, boot-order

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on my acer computer and I'd like to change the boot order but I forgot the password....I want to boot my USB Drive first (with windows).
I found some topics about that but when I type 'efibootmgr' in a terminal, I get this :`efibootmgr: EFI variables are not supported on this system.`

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Simple answer: you can't.

Comment: The error message may be caused by booting the USB in legacy mode instead of UEFI mode.  How it boots -- legacy/UEFI is set in the UEFI settings/BIOS...

Comment: Do you have access to your bootloader?

Comment: I don't know what is exactly a bootloader, but I have access to grub